# How can I implement SF Pro Rounded text in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, text

Below is the code on which I am trying to implement SF pro-rounded text in Swift. I am new to Swift and am not entirely sure how to edit fonts.
Text("Levitate")
.font(.largeTitle)
.fontWeight(.semibold)
.foregroundColor(Color.white)
.multilineTextAlignment(.center)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/font/system(_:design:weight:)

E.g.:

```
Text("My text")
    .font(.system(.largeTitle, design: .rounded, weight: .semibold))
```